# Locker Studio Session Length between multiple events

Tags: database, charts, locker

I'm a seasoned user of Amplitude, but recently I started using Locker Studio.
Here's my situation:

- I have a `event_timestamp`, `event_type` and `session_id` for each event I log;
- For each `session_id` I want to:

  - take the `event_timestamp` when `event_type = 1` (Session Start);
  - take the `event_timestamp` when `event_type = 2` (Session Start);
  - (ignore any other `event_type`'s value);
  - compute the diff (Session Length)
- (Know how) Then with these, I want to calculate the average and show it on a score card.

With Amplitude, this was pretty easy. Can anybody help me to achieve this goal on LockerStudio?

Thank you!

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: This is not about writing SQL. There's no SQL involved in LockerStudio. It's all about using the GUI and sometimes some formula (not SQL).
And this is the nature of my question, so I can't show you anything beside the detailed description I put in my question.

Comment: If no SQL is involved, how's the <sql> tag relevant?

Comment: behind there's a SQL datasource.

Comment: If you hover the <sql> tag you can read _Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation_. Perhaps a tag for your dbms would make more sense.